How to use `Rcpp` to implement a similar function for regression analysis of `lm` functions in R?
In order to speed up the calculation for very large matrices, I use Rcpp to perform the calculation, which involves regression analysis. I noticed in r's documentation that lm uses the qr decomposition method. I tried programming, and the code for regression analysis is as follows.
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(bigmemory)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

List lm_armadillo_with_p_values(arma::mat mat) {
  // seprate matrix to y and x
  arma::mat X_mat = mat.cols(1, mat.n_cols - 1);
  arma::colvec y_vec = mat.col(0);
  // Rcpp::Rcout << "lm data of X_mat is " << X_mat << std::endl;
  // Rcpp::Rcout << "lm data of y_mat is " << y_vec << std::endl;

  // Check matrix dimension
  if (X_mat.n_rows != y_vec.n_rows) {
    stop("Number of rows in X does not match length of y.");
  }
  
  // // Check whether epi is the inverse of an effect
  // arma::vec epi_tmp1 = X_mat.col(0)+X_mat.col(2);
  // arma::vec epi_tmp2 = X_mat.col(1)+X_mat.col(2);
  // 
  // Rcpp::Rcout << "X_mat is " << X_mat.rows(0,10) << std::endl;
  // Rcpp::Rcout << "epi_tmp1 is " << epi_tmp1.rows(0,10) << std::endl;
  

  // // Calculate regression coefficient (least square method)
  // arma::vec beta = solve(X_mat, y_vec);  // beta = (X'X)^(-1) X'y

  arma::mat Q,R;

  // Calculate regression coefficient (QR decomposition)
  arma::qr_econ(Q,R,X_mat); // 将 X 分解为 Q 和 R
  // arma::qr(Q,R,X_mat); // 将 X 分解为 Q 和 R
  Rcpp::Rcout << "R " << R << std::endl;

  // beta = R^(-1) * Q^T * y

  // Calculated regression coefficient
  arma::vec beta = inv(R) * Q.t() * y_vec;

  // Calculated predicted value
  arma::colvec y_hat = X_mat * beta;

  // Calculated residual
  arma::colvec residuals = y_vec - y_hat;

  // Calculation standard error
  arma::mat X_transpose = X_mat.t();
  arma::mat var_beta = inv(X_transpose * X_mat) * var(residuals);  // (X'X)^(-1) * Var(ε)
  arma::colvec se_beta = sqrt(var_beta.diag());  // 提取标准误差

  // Calculate the t statistic
  arma::colvec t_stat = beta / se_beta;

  // Calculating P-values (two-tail test)
  int n = X_mat.n_rows;  
  int p = X_mat.n_cols;  
  int df = n - p;    
  NumericVector p_values(t_stat.n_elem);
  // Iterate over the t_stat to compute the corresponding p-value
  for (size_t i = 0; i < t_stat.n_elem; ++i) {
    p_values[i] = 2 * (1 - R::pt(std::abs(t_stat[i]), df, true, false));
  }

  // R-squared
  double ss_total = sum(square(y_vec - mean(y_vec)));
  double ss_residual = sum(square(residuals));
  double r_squared = 1 - (ss_residual / ss_total);

  // return result
  return List::create(
    Named("coefficients") = beta,
    // Named("residuals") = residuals,
    Named("standard_errors") = se_beta,
    Named("t_stat") = t_stat,
    Named("p_values") = p_values,
    Named("r_squared") = r_squared
  );
}


In most cases, the results of my code are similar to the lm results of R. However, when the two factor variables in the regression analysis are negative to each other, the results are very different.
It can be seen that when the last two columns are negative to each other, the R output result will not output the coefficient and p value corresponding to epi, while the results obtained by qr decomposition in Rcpp still have the results of epi, and the values are greatly different. How should I deal with this situation? How does R implement this process?
Input matrix data, head(10):
head(subdata)
            y   S1_24442454 S3_229468875         epi
1 -34.4703467 -1.144917e-16  -0.19933658  0.19933658
2  -5.9188034 -4.700016e-17   0.15319562 -0.15319562
3  -4.9626772 -1.452831e-16   0.11634120 -0.11634120
4   2.1563250 -8.153200e-17   0.14881466 -0.14881466
5   0.1383353 -8.023096e-18   0.07223461 -0.07223461
6   2.3299190  7.329207e-17   0.19493439 -0.19493439

My result of Rcpp code:
R    3.6380e-15   7.1486e-02  -7.6010e-02
            0   3.4954e+00  -3.0080e+00
            0            0   1.8043e+00

0caught exception times
$coefficients
              [,1]
[1,] -7.301777e+14
[2,]  5.700982e+00
[3,]  6.074322e+00

$standard_errors
             [,1]
[1,] 1.726830e+15
[2,] 3.493131e+00
[3,] 3.480988e+00

$t_stat
           [,1]
[1,] -0.4228429
[2,]  1.6320553
[3,]  1.7449992

$p_values
[1] 0.67259580 0.10331161 0.08161319

$r_squared
[1] -0.000798888

R lm result:
>fit.lm <- lm(as.formula(paste("y ~ -1 +",total_ma_names[m],"+",total_ma_names[n],"+ epi")),
                   data=subdata)
>summary(fit.lm)

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste("y ~ -1 +", total_ma_names[m], 
    "+", total_ma_names[n], "+ epi")), data = subdata)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-32.395  -4.228  -0.569   3.341  18.509 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
S1_24442454  -4.471e+14  1.720e+15  -0.260 0.794995    
S3_229468875  1.067e+01  2.920e+00   3.654 0.000286 ***
epi                  NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6.25 on 490 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02689,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02292 
F-statistic:  6.77 on 2 and 490 DF,  p-value: 0.001258


Your data are not compatible with the assumptions for a linear regression.  The columns in X need to be linearly independent.  This is something you can test in R (and most other languages and packages) with kappa or its reciprocal rcond.  On your toy data set:
> X <- as.matrix(read.table(text=" -1.144917e-16  -0.19933658  0.19933658
 -4.700016e-17   0.15319562 -0.15319562
 -1.452831e-16   0.11634120 -0.11634120
 -8.153200e-17   0.14881466 -0.14881466
 -8.023096e-18   0.07223461 -0.07223461
  7.329207e-17   0.19493439 -0.19493439"))
. + > X
               V1         V2         V3
[1,] -1.14492e-16 -0.1993366  0.1993366
[2,] -4.70002e-17  0.1531956 -0.1531956
[3,] -1.45283e-16  0.1163412 -0.1163412
[4,] -8.15320e-17  0.1488147 -0.1488147
[5,] -8.02310e-18  0.0722346 -0.0722346
[6,]  7.32921e-17  0.1949344 -0.1949344
> rcond(X)
[1] 3.66668e-17
> kappa(X)
[1] 2.57259e+16
> 

Amazingly, the help page for rcond and kappa does not say much about cutoffs ... but 3.6e-17 and 2.6e17 are essentially, respectively, zero and infinite. (There is a vague recollection of seeing values smaller / larger than 1e-3 / 1e3 as indicative of a problem but have no reference handy right now.)
Now, such low / high values are exactly what you expect when you create a matrix where one column is a linear combination of the other columns here with a col3 being a [0, -1] multiple of the first two.
Now, R helps you here. As you really only have two columns you only get two coefficients back, and R refuses to create an estimate for the third. As it can't.
But calling QR directly in (Rcpp)Armadillo without checking  blindly computes values and gets you nonsense. As is expected for an ill-conditioned problem. That is exactly described in the manual page for its demo function fastLm():

Lastly, one must be be careful in timing comparisons of lm and
friends versus this approach based on ‘Armadillo’. The reason that
‘Armadillo’ can do something like lm.fit faster than the
functions in the stats package is because ‘Armadillo’ uses the
Lapack version of the QR decomposition while the stats package
uses a modified Linpack version.  Hence ‘Armadillo’ uses level-3
BLAS code whereas the stats package uses level-1 BLAS.  However,
‘Armadillo’ will either fail or, worse, produce completely
incorrect answers on rank-deficient model matrices whereas the
functions from the stats package will handle them properly due to
the modified Linpack code.


An example of the type of situation requiring extra care in
checking for rank deficiency is a two-way layout with missing
cells (see the examples section).  These cases require a special
pivoting scheme of “pivot only on (apparent) rank deficiency”
which is not part of conventional linear algebra software.

The referenced example there is something you could look at, it also uses kappa.

Thank you very much for your meticulous answers. If I want to call R's lm function in Rcpp, how do I call it and pass in the model parameters?

Feel free to accept the answer if it help (click on the 'tick' mark you are shown).  As far calling this directly, as far as I know there is no API for calling the internals you are seeking directly.
